# A completely reducible module is isomorphic to its associated graded module?

Tags: commutative-algebra, representation-theory

> If $F.(M)$ is a (finite) filtration of a finitely generated module $M$ that is completely reducible, then $M \cong \operatorname{gr}_{F.(M)}$?

Let $0=F_{n+1}(M) \leq F_{n}(M) \leq \cdots \leq F_{1}(M) \leq F_{0}(M)=M$ be the filtration. How would you begin to prove this?

Comment: Hint: Can you prove it when the filtration has all factors irreducible?

Answer (score 1):

Proof by induction on $n$.

If $n=0$, there is nothing to prove. If $n=1$ use that $F_1(M)$ is a direct summand of $M$. In general, $F_1(M)$ is also completely reducible, so $F_1(M)$ is isomorphic to its associated graded module. Since $M\simeq M/F_1(M)\oplus F_1(M)$ we are done.